# How to add an UIView from a XIB file as a subview to another Xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, xib

I am trying to add a custom `UIView` that I created in XIB, to my view controller in my `main.storyboard` as a subview. How can I do this?

`matchScrollView` (tag 1) is the `UIScrollView` in view controller in main.storyboard, while `matchView` (tag 2) is the custom `UIView` I created in another XIB file.

With the press of a button i want to have the custom `UIView` added to the `UIScrollView` as a subview. But how can i actually make it show up on display? I guess i have yet to alloc and init it, along with indicate position and such, but how can i do that? I tried different ways without success. I can create `UIViews` programmatically, but have yet to find a way to just load the `UIView` from XIB.

```
-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIScrollView *matchScrollView = (UIScrollView *) [self.view viewWithTag:1];
    UIView *matchView = (UIView *) [self.view viewWithTag:2];
    [matchScrollView addSubview:matchView];

}
```

The reason that I am creating my custom `UIView` in another XIB file instead of directly implementing it on my main.storyboard view controller, is because I want to re-use the same view multiple times. So the `UIScrollView` has a numerous subviews of `UIViews`.

I was hoping I could create numerous instances of `MatchView` and add them all to `matchScrollView` as subviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is completely normal. The way Apple designed it doesn't allow to reuse custom views with their own xib into other xibs.

Lets say you have a custom view named HeaderView with a custom xib named HeaderView.xib. And lets say you want to be able to, in another xib named GlobalView.xib, drag a subview and specify its class to be of type HeaderView expecting it to load that view from HeaderView.xib and insert it inplace. You can do it like this:

A) Make sure File's Owner in HeaderView.xib is set to be HeaderView class.

B) Go to your GlobalView.xib, drag the subview and make it of class HeaderView.

C) In HeaverView.m implement initWithCoder, if after loading the view there aren't subviews means it got loaded from GlobalView, then load it manually from the correct nib, connect the IBOutlets and set the frame and autoresizingmasks if you want to use the GlobalView's frame (this is usually what you want).

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self.subviews.count == 0) { //means view got loaded from GlobalView.xib or other external nib, cause there aren't any subviews
        HeaverView *viewFromNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaverView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
        //Now connect IBOutlets
        self.myLabel1 = viewFromNib.myLabel1;
        self.myLabel2 = viewFromNib.myLabel2;
        self.myLabel3 = viewFromNib.myLabel3;
        [viewFromNib setFrame:self.bounds];
        [viewFromNib setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [self addSubview:viewFromNib];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the InitwithCoder was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: quick question, what if i make the subview in GlobalView.xib programmatically instead of in XIB? So i can create numerous instances in the future. I tried - MatchView *contentView = [[MatchView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 327, 120)]; then adding it as subview. But the UIView is blank instead. i guess i gotta call the initwithcoder instead?

Comment: if you want to create an instance of HeaderView in code, and add it to your GlobalView, then load HeaderView from nib (not with initWithFrame) and add it as subview same way initWithCoder does in the sample above:

        HeaverView *viewFromNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaverView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;

In iOS there are two ways to instantiate UIViews, with init or initWithFrame (which doesn't use NIB's) or from a nib (which internally calls initWithCoder and not initWithFrame)

Comment: I tried this, but got "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". Also, is that really enough too initialize it? I would assume you would have to give it co-ordinates or something to tell it where in view to add it. I am sorry, i am very new to iOS programming as this is my first project, so i get confused easily. i also read http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/recipe-6-creating-a-custom-uiview-using-a-nib/

Comment: Place breakpoints and debug your code. Verify that doing MatchView *viewFromNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MatchView " owner:self options:nil].firstObject; returns a UIView from the nib with all subviews and IBOutlets initialized. After that, you can set up any frame you want and finally add it as a subview with [self.view addSubview: viewFromNib]

Comment: If i delete the IBOutlets, then it works. So i must be doing something wrong with the IBOutlets, i will figure it out. Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: In MatchView.xib, make sure the main view has the field Class in the 'Identity Inspector' (right pane) set to MatchView. Also, make all IBOutlets are connected to MatchView.h.

Comment: Yea, those are already set up like that. Which is why im having trouble locating the uncaught exception error.

Comment: EDIT: Got it working now. Apparently i had connected the IBOutlets to File's owner which was set to Matchview. Deleted that and connected them to MatchView directly, works now!